# Filter records on report where group sum is greater than 1

Tags: reporting

I'm writing a report that groups accounts by account name, and summing up a formula field that simply returns 1 for each account. Yes, I'm trying to find duplicate accounts.

I have a report that shows thousands of accounts with most of them showing a 1 for the count of duplicates. However, there are others with 2 or more in the group. Is there a way to filter out the 1's and only show records where the sum of 1's are greater than 1?

In SQL terms, this would be the equivalent to:

```
SELECT Name, Count(Id)
FROM Account
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Count(Id) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no way to filter on a sum (I was running in to the same issue while doing similar data work in my org). I ended up having to export to Excel & do the bulk for my work there. Far from ideal.

Have you tried a SOQL query? It didn't work in my situation, but it might work for you.